# mvc3 ajax server side validation

Tags: ajax, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, server-side

I've created a simple login form that I'd like to validate via ajax.

What's the most appropriate method to display the server-side validation errors produced by MVC?  Is converting the error to a JSON result and stripping out the error message appropriate?  If not, then what would be?

Currently what I have is posting correctly, but the entire form comes back.  The goal is just to display the server-side errors on the form without a postback/refresh.  Thanks in advance...here is my code:

### Main View - Login.vbhtml

```
@ModelType UHCO_MVC_Agency.LoginModel

<div class="error-container">@Html.ValidationSummary(True)</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="login-form" class="span6">
            @Using Html.BeginForm()
               @<fieldset>
                  <legend>Log in to your account now</legend>
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                     <div class="span12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.UserName)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.UserName, New With {.class = "span12", .placeholder = "Username"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.UserName)
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                     <div class="span12">
                        <label for="Password">Your password</label>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(Function(m) m.Password, New With {.class = "span12", .placeholder = "Password", .type = "password"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Password)
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                     <div class="span12">
                        <label for="RememberMe" class="checkbox clearfix">
                           @Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(m) m.RememberMe)
                           Remember me next time I visit
                        </label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary input-small" value="submit">Log in</button>
               </fieldset>
            End Using
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

### Controller - AccountController.vb

```
<HttpPost()> _
Public Function Login(ByVal model As LoginModel, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String, ByVal returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
   Dim res As New LoginResponse()
   Try
      'login here
   If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) AndAlso Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) Then
      res.Status = "Success"
      Return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Account")
   End If
   Catch ex As Exception
      If Not HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() Then
         ModelState.AddModelError("", ExceptionWrapper.Wrap(ex).ExceptionMessage())
         Return View("Login", model)
      Else
         res.Status = "Failed"
         res.Errors.Add(ExceptionWrapper.Wrap(ex).ExceptionMessage())
         Return Json(res)
      End If
   End Try
   ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
   Return View(model)
End Function
```

### Application.js

```
$("#login-form form").live().submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("ok");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a C# version of the solution. I believe,  it should be easy to convert to corresponding VB.NET version

using **JSON** is absolutely a nice way to do this.

First thing. I would change the `POST` action method to handle my request for Ajax requests and return `JSON` response back.

To hold my Error response, I will create a class like this

```
public class LoginResponse
{
  public string Status { set;get;}
  public List<string> Errors { set;get;}

  public LoginResponse()
  {
    Errors=new List<string>();   
  }       
}
```

And in our `POST` action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
  if(Request.Ajax)
  {
       var res=new LoginResponse();
     //Do your Validations, If everything is fine send Success JSON
        res.Status="Success";

     //else, Lets return a JSON with errors
        res.Status="Failed";
        res.Errors.Add("Email does not exist in Earth and Mars");
        res.Errors.Add("Password contain the word black magic");

     return Json (res);
  }
  else
  {
     //Do the normal Processing for Non Ajax requests here
  }
}
```

So if there is some error you want to return back to the client, you will send JSON in this format

```
{
    "Status": "Failed",
    "Errors": [  "Email does not exist",  "Passoword is worse"  ]
}
```

And If everything is fine, We will send JSON like this

```
{
    "Status": "Success"
}
```

Now in our view, we will get rid of the Ajax form and use the Normal form tag with some pure jQuery.

```
@ModelType UHCO_MVC_Agency.LoginModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  //Here your for elements

  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
}
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     $.post("@Url.Action("Login","User")", $("form").serialize(), function (r) {
       if(r.Status=="Success")
       {
         //Login is success . do whatever you want.
       }
       else
       {
         //Lets get the Errors from our JSON
         $.each(r.Errors,function(index,item){
             //Lets show the error
              $("#errorSummary").append(item);
         }  
       }
     });

});    
</script>
```

**EDIT :** Change your js code like this and see what happens

```
$("#login-form form").live('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  //the code

});
```

Comment: Shyju - Thank for the detailed response.  I tried implementing your solution, but for some reason the post is occurring twice? I've edited the original code.

Comment: @Michael: Check whether you have the submit event binded in more than one place.

Comment: nope...1st thing I checked :( Can't award bounty for another 5 hours, but it's yours...for some reason I can't debug where it's coming from.  I assumed it was because the page actually posts (non ajax) then posts via ajax, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Michael: Since we have ` e.preventDefault();` in our submit code. It wont do the normal form posting. So i assume it does a formsubmit before it hit our handler. Try to comment/ remove other javacsipt associated with this view and narrow down the issue.

Comment: I would do this : Create a new View and add only relevant items step by step and debug. Then figure out what is wrong (Additional) with the first view.

Comment: I believe the issue is that the form is still not being submitted via ajax.  Stepping through the code I see that HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() is returning false.

Comment: is your submit button id is btnSubmit ?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind taking a look at the original post - I edited the code to match what I have now.  I bound the function to the form submit action...I didn't bind it to the button's click event.

Comment: @Michael: I doubt your js code doing something wrong. Try the one i added to my answer.

Comment: Finally got it to work.  I think the problem was the javascript for the form was outside the view in a separate file?  not sure, but i moved it in and it worked like a charm.  I may have another question, but THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VB guy, by any means, but I think what you need to do is this:

1)  In your controller you need to check and see if you have arrived via AJAX.  You can either send an extra piece of information along with the data to indicated this, or using `SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` and checking for XMLHTTPRequest which is sent by most common libraries.

2) If the page was, in fact, requested via AJAX then you can take a different process when packaging the output.  Return only the JSON and then parse it on the client side manipulating the DOM.